# unable to boot my MacBook after FileVault 2 activation

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, filevault, data-recovery, unlock

after activation of FileVault 2 I am unable to boot my computer, the apple sign turns into a prohibitory sign with a spinning circle beneath it , that spins forever. I really need the data on this computer :( and I can not afford the very expensive data recovery services . Does anyone know how I can overcome this problem or at least decrypt and save my data ?

Comment: Did you write down the encryption key you got when FV was set up?

Comment: You have a backup, right?

Answer (score 4):

You can press the option + R key to boot into recovery mode. Then using Disk utility and follow this guide to decrypt the partition:

http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/using-the-command-line-to-unlock-or-decrypt-your-filevault-2-encrypted-boot-drive/

Comment: Yes I have the encryption key but when in booting in recovery mode the option to unlock or decrypt is grayed out and unfortunately I have no backup of the data ( which is very important worth of 1.5 yrs of work my whole thesis and papers are in there). I just want to get my data out of ther safely . I will try using the command line if that is safe . I am very frustrated.

Comment: I think calling Apple support would be the best way to proceed from here, even if you need to pay a little. 1,5 years of work and no backup...